# How to get particular values from nested JSON response?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, json

I have received `JSON` response look like (below added) :

```
response : {

     A =  { 
             latitude = "0";
             longitude = "0";

          };

     B =  { 
             latitude = "0";
             longitude = "0";

          };
}
```

I need to get A, B, C,.. values of lat, longs. and store into one array. Here I can get by `valueforkey :@"A"` method but I don't know the response first object may be 1, 2 , 3 whatever. Please give me one good solution for this problem.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: Well, first get some valid JSON -- the above is missing a `{`, at least.  Then go to json.org to learn the JSON syntax.  Then parse the JSON with NSJSONSerialization (which apparently you've already done, since the above is an NSLog of a dictionary (absent the opening '{')), then access the returned dictionary to fetch "response", returning a dictionary.  Now you can access the "A" and "B" dictionaries, and the "latitude" and "longitude" entries within.  NSLog at each step to understand what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSArray *firstLevelValues = [response allValues];
NSArray *lats = [firstLevelValues valueForKey:@"latitude"];
NSArray *longs = [firstLevelValues valueForKey:@"longitude"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` have 2 methods  `allKeys` and `allValues`. So If you want to get all keys in **response** object use following syntax:

```
NSArray *allKeys = [dict valueForKey:@"response"];
```

If you want to get value of latitude and longitude then iterate over allKeys in for loop.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"response":@{@"A":@{@"latitude":@"0",@"longitude":@"0"},
                                     @"B":@{@"latitude":@"1",@"longitude":@"1"}}};

NSDictionary *response = [dict valueForKey:@"response"];
NSArray *allKeys = [dict valueForKey:@"response"];

for (NSString *keyName in allKeys) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[response objectForKey:keyName]);
    NSString *latitude = [[response objectForKey:keyName] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
    NSString *longitude = [[response objectForKey:keyName] objectForKey:@"longitude"];

}
```

Comment: In the loop you should first set `NSDictionary* letterDict = response[keyName];` and then use `letterDict` in the subsequent lines.  This isn't so much to "optimize" as to provide a way to debug if necessary (and to shorten your statements so they're easier to "grok").

Comment: @HotLicks Yup you can do that also. I didn't do that because it has only 2 values. You can also use `objectForKeyPath` if there are more level in JSON

Comment: @Ajay Accepting and Unaccepting answer without any reason wont help us. Pls specify reason if you feel that's not feeding your need.